# (VS2010 C++) Execute a command every time the program is run?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

The IDE I'm using is VS2010 for writing C++

I want to execute the command `cmd C:\utilities\unix\tail.exe -f -n15 $(ProjectDir)Log.txt` every time the program I'm coding is run from within the IDE.  (This command should open a console to track changes made to the file Log.txt)

There are ways to make a command run every time the program is built, but I can't find a way to make a command run whenever the program itself is run, even if it's already built.  Where or how might I be able to set that kind of thing up?

I've tried putting `$(TargetPath) & C:\utilities\unix\tail.exe -f -n15 $(ProjectDir)Log.txt` into the project's Properties->Debugging->Command (TargetPath is the full name of the debug executable) but VS reads the entire thing as a filename and gets confused.

Comment: I ended up adding the command as an "external tool", then customized the UI to include the command right next to the run button.  Which is sufficient I think!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file `run.cmd` for example next to the vcxproj file, which would contain:

```
%1
C:\utilities\unix\tail.exe -f -n15 %2Log.txt
```

And then in `Properties->Debugging->Command` you write:

```
$(ProjectDir)\run.cmd
```

and in `Command Arguments` you write:

```
"$(TargetPath)" "$(ProjectDir)"
```

I may have misspelled the macros, but you get the idea: it executes first your program and then whatever you want.

Edit: Unfortunately it works only if you start without debugging (<kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>), because otherwise the debugger tries to attach to `run.cmd` and complains that the format is unsupported.

Comment: VS says the file is unrecognized, sadly.  Though that was pretty impressive, I think it's VS just saying "Command" when it really means "Debug Executable"

Comment: @Clairvoire Ah, yes, because the debugger tries to attach to `run.cmd` (see my update)